# Flutter GridView.count unwanted padding / space between elements

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a GridView.builder to generate 2 'columns' of elements

This is my code:

```
ListView(
 children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * 0.05),
              child: Text(
                "MyText",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
              ),
            ),
            GridView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: screenWidth * 0.05, right: screenWidth * 0.05),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: 12,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenWidth / 4.1 + screenWidth / 11,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: screenWidth / 4.1,
                            width: screenWidth / 2.5,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: screenWidth / 11,
                            width: screenWidth / 2.5,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
  ],
        ),
```

[image: GridView.count_padding]

As you can see in the image the title "MyText" and the elements of the GridView aren't vertically aligned. (Even though they have the same padding).

Is there a possibility to make them have the same alignment?

Thanks!

Comment: You're adding a right padding to the grid

Comment: Yes, that s on purpose. But it goed more to the left/ right than the Value i assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way to fix this, but that may require a redesign of how your widgets are laid out. I worked out a quick fix for you. Code below

```
ListView(
 children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * 0.05),
              child: Text(
                "MyText",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
              ),
            ),
            GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: 12,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenWidth / 4.1 + screenWidth / 11,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: screenWidth / 4.1,
                            width: screenWidth / 2.5,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: screenWidth / 11,
                            width: screenWidth / 2.5,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
  ],
        ),
```

You can use the 'Flutter Inspector' - 'Show Debug Paint' to view the layout

Comment: So basically, the Grid has standard a padding of 16? Your solution works perfectly but is it a coincidence? Cuz it's important that it's aligned on every device.

Comment: You were right it only aligned properly on a particular emulator. I removed the padding on the GridView.builder and tested it on the Pixel 3XL, Nexus 10 & Nexus 9 emulators and also my device (Redmi Note 8) and now it aligns perfectly. Should work well across devices now.